# Getting base name of the source file at compile time

Tags: c++, c, makefile, macros, compiler-construction

I'm using GCC; __FILE__ returns the current source file's entire path and name: `/path/to/file.cpp`. Is there a way to get just the file's name `file.cpp` (without its path) at compile time? Is it possible to do this in a portable way? Can template meta programming be applied to strings?

I am using this in an error logging macro. I really do not want my source's full path making its way into the executable.

Comment: The file name is the name given to the compiler.

Comment: My source has a directory structure, so I can't pass just the file name to the compiler. Furthermore, I'm using CMake which seems to always give full paths.

I think this question should keep the c++ tag because template meta programming may be a valid answer?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31050113/2506522

Comment: @betontalpfa More like that one is a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using a `make` program, you should be able to munge the filename beforehand and pass it as a macro to `gcc` to be used in your program. For example, in your `makefile`, change the line:

```
file.o: file.c
    gcc -c -o file.o src/file.c
```

to:

```
file.o: src/file.c
    gcc "-DMYFILE=\"`basename $<`\"" -c -o file.o src/file.c
```

This will allow you to use `MYFILE` in your code instead of `__FILE__`.

The use of `basename` of the source file `$<` means you can use it in generalized rules such as `.c.o`. The following code illustrates how it works. First, a `makefile`:

```
mainprog: main.o makefile
    gcc -o mainprog main.o

main.o: src/main.c makefile
    gcc "-DMYFILE=\"`basename $<`\"" -c -o main.o src/main.c
```

Then a file in a subdirectory, `src/main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf ("file = %s\n", MYFILE);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, a transcript showing it running:

```
pax:~$ mainprog
file = main.c
```

Note the `file =` line which contains *only* the base name of the file, not the directory name as well.

Comment: Note that names starting with double-underscore (or underscore and a capital letter) are reserved for the implementation.  It would be better to avoid `__MYFILE__`, probably using `MYFILE` or something similar.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of a direct way.  You could use:

```
#line 1 "filename.c"
```

at the top of the source file to set the value of `__FILE__`, but I'm not sure that that's much better than hard coding it. or just using a #define to create your own macro.

Another option might be to pass the name from your Makefile using -D and $(shell basename $<)

Edit: If you use a #define or the -D option, you should create your own new name and not try to redefine `__FILE__`.

Comment: Messing with pre-defined macros is not a good idea. As they are not defined in the same way as other macros attempts to change them will be compiler specific.

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged CMake, here's a neat solution to add to your CMakeLists.txt:
(copied from http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-December/048281.html ). (Note : some compilers don't support per-file COMPILE_DEFINITIONS ! but it works with gcc)

```
set(SRCS a/a.cpp b/b.cpp c/c.cpp d/d.cpp)

foreach(f IN LISTS SRCS)
 get_filename_component(b ${f} NAME)
 set_source_files_properties(${f} PROPERTIES
  COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "MYSRCNAME=${b}")
endforeach()

add_executable(foo ${SRCS})
```

Note : For my application I needed to escape the filename string like this:

```
COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "MYSRCNAME=\"${b}\"")
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider this simple source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    puts(__FILE__);
    return(0);
}
```

On Solaris, with GCC 4.3.1, if I compile this using:

```
gcc -o x x.c && ./x
```

the output is '`x.c`'  If I compile it using:

```
gcc -o x $PWD/x.c && ./x
```

then __FILE__ maps to the full path ('`/work1/jleffler/tmp/x.c`').  If I compile it using:

```
gcc -o x ../tmp/x.c && ./x
```

then __FILE__ maps to '`../tmp/x.c`'.

So, basically, __FILE__ is the pathname of the source file.  If you build with the name you want to see in the object, all is well.

If that is impossible (for whatever reason), then you will have to get into the fixes suggested by other people.

Answer (score 4):

What does your error logging macro do? I would presume at some point the macro eventually calls a function of some kind in order to do the logging, why not have the called function strip off the path component at runtime?

```
#define LOG(message) _log(__FILE__, message)

void _log(file, message)
{
  #ifndef DEBUG
  strippath(file); // in some suitable way
  #endif

  cerr << "Log: " << file << ": " << message; // or whatever
}
```

Comment: That stops the full filename from being output to the logs but still has it contained within the executable. I think that's what the questioner was after.  Still, it's a good solution so no downvote.

Comment: Read this article about underscores: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: I'd much rather have a compile time solution. I think it's sloppy to have development paths in the finial executable.

Comment: Watch for the overhead of stripping the string every time you call your log function...

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it with template metaprogramming, but there's no built-in way to do it.

EDIT: Hm, correction. According to [one page I just saw](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/C_CPP/comp.lang.c/2006-02/msg00698.html), GCC uses the path that it's given for the file. If it's given the full name, it'll embed it; if it's only given a relative one, it'll only embed that. I haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: I thought about the metaprogramming, but I never even suceeded in passing __FILE__ as template argument.

Comment: I'm looking into how to do it via metaprogramming, mostly for my own personal enlightenment. It looks like it should be possible. I'll edit my answer if/when I come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The question is already 12 years old and back in 2008 this solution wasn't available, but

Starting with GCC 8 and CLANG 10, one can use the option [-fmacro-prefix-map](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fmacro-prefix-map).
Acording to GCC Manual:

> -fmacro-prefix-map=old=new
> When preprocessing files residing in directory *‘old’*, expand the
> `__FILE__` and `__BASE_FILE__` macros as if the files resided in
> directory *‘new’* instead. This can be used to change an absolute path to
> a relative path by using *‘.’* for *new* which can result in more
> reproducible builds that are location independent. This option also
> affects `__builtin_FILE()` during compilation. See also
> ‘-ffile-prefix-map’.

For instance, the makefile in my IDE (Eclipse) includes the following parameter for GCC for some files: `-fmacro-prefix-map="../Sources/"=.`
Thus, my debug logs always show only the filenames, without the paths.

Note: GCC 8.1 and Clang 10 were released in May 2018 and March 2020, respectively. So, currently, in September of 2020, only some of my environments support -fmacro-prefix-map.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the idea from Glomek, it can be automated like this:

Source file x.c

```
#line 1 MY_FILE_NAME
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(__FILE__);
    return(0);
}
```

Compilation line (beware the single quotes outside the double quotes):

```
gcc -DMY_FILE_NAME='"abcd.c"' -o x x.c
```

The output is '`abcd.c`'.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy with cmake.

`DefineRelativeFilePaths.cmake`

```
function (cmake_define_relative_file_paths SOURCES)
  foreach (SOURCE IN LISTS SOURCES)
    file (
      RELATIVE_PATH RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH
      ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} ${SOURCE}
    )

    set_source_files_properties (
      ${SOURCE} PROPERTIES
      COMPILE_DEFINITIONS __RELATIVE_FILE_PATH__="${RELATIVE_SOURCE_PATH}"
    )
  endforeach ()
endfunction ()
```

Somewhere in `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set (SOURCES ${SOURCES}
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/common.c"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.c"
)

include (DefineRelativeFilePaths)
cmake_define_relative_file_paths ("${SOURCES}")
```

`cmake .. && make clean && make VERBOSE=1`

```
cc ... -D__RELATIVE_FILE_PATH__="src/main.c" ... -c src/main.c
```

That's it. Now you can make pretty log messages.

```
#define ..._LOG_HEADER(target) \
  fprintf(target, "%s %s:%u - ", __func__, __RELATIVE_FILE_PATH__, __LINE__);
```

> func src/main.c:22 - my error

PS It is better to declear in `config.h.in` -> `config.h`

```
#ifndef __RELATIVE_FILE_PATH__
#define __RELATIVE_FILE_PATH__ __FILE__
#endif
```

So your linter wan't provide rain of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign `__FILE__` to a string, and then call _splitpath() to rip the pieces out of it.  This might be a Windows/MSVC-only solution, honestly I don't know.

I know you were looking for a compile-time solution and this is a run-time solution, but I figured since you were using the filename to do (presumably run-time) error logging, this could be a simple straightforward way to get you what you need.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it's been suggested already, twice. Please upvote an existing solution when you can.

Comment: Nobody else suggested using _splitpath().  I have found that many people don't know such a function exists, and they end up parsing the string themselves.  My solution will remain.

Answer (score 0):

You can take __FILE__ and the strip off the part of path you don't want (programatically). If basedir satisfies your needs, then fine. Otherwise, get source dir root from your build system, and the rest should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue; found a different resolution, just thought I'd share it:

In a header file included in all my other files:

```
static char * file_bname = NULL;
#define __STRIPPED_FILE__   (file_bname ?: (file_bname = basename(__FILE__)))
```

Hope this is useful to someone else as well :)