# Getting base filename define in scons

Tags: scons, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to generate a per-sourcefile macro that will hold the base file name of the source file. This is described for make [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237542/learning-the-source-codes-filename-at-compile-time).

I tried to override the Object builder, but it didn't work...
I tried to do what is described [here](http://www.scons.org/wiki/SharedLibrarySignatureOverride).

```
def my_object_builder(env, target, source, **kwargs):
    """A builder that calls the Object builder, with the addition of defining
    a macro that holds the source file's basename  
    """
    if SCons.Util.is_List(source):
        if len(source) > 1:
            raise ValueError('cannot pass a list of sources to Object builder: %s',
                             [str(x) for x in source])
        else:
            source, = source

    if 'CPPDEFINES' not in kwargs: 
        kwargs['CPPDEFINES'] = []
    kwargs['CPPDEFINES'].append(('__MY_FILENAME', 
                                 os.path.basename(str(source))))

    ret = env._Object(target=target, 
                  source=source, 
                  **kwargs)
    return ret
```

Then, replacing the builders:

```
env['BUILDERS']['_Object'] = env['BUILDERS']['Object'] 
env['BUILDERS']['Object'] = my_object_builder
```

This didn't work. I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'src_suffixes'
```

I think it has to do with something with Environment's MethodWrapper, but I couldn't verify.

Maybe I'm going for this from the wrong angle. Maybe I should change the environment for each source file (seems like a lot of work...)

The main requirement is that the usage will be seamless. I don't want users to have to call a MyObjectBuilder class. Also, the StaticLibrary Builder should call the new Object builder.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

BugoK.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It's a one liner...

```
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-D__MY_FILENAME=\\"${SOURCE.file}\\"'])
```

Just adding a define which is rule based.
The quotes are just an addition to be able to printf it without strigifying the expression.